# Apple Combine's PassthroughSubject not Compiling

Tags: swift, combine

I have a class that fetches the user's current location, and I want to be able to pass the most-recently fetched `CLLocation` or an `Error` to a `SwiftUI` `View`.

Below is the class that is responsible for location-fetching:

```swift
class LocationProvider: NSObject, BindableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    // MARK: - BindableObject

    var willChange = PassthroughSubject<CLLocation, Error>()

    // MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        willChange.send(location)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        willChange.send(completion: .failure(.unknown))
    }

}
```

I get the following compilation error: `Type 'LocationProvider' does not conform to protocol 'BindableObject'` when I use `Error` as the failure type. However, if I change `Error` to `Never`, then the file compiles successfully.

What do I need to change so that I can pass a `CLLocation` or an `Error`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The publisher type in a BindableObject's `willChange` *must* have an error type of Never. If that's not what you want, you can't use a simple BindableObject's `willChange` here.

What you are after *might* be a bindable object whose publisher publishes a Result. That can contain either the location or the error and you can deal with it further down the pipeline, if you see what I mean.